# show div on a click, but exist div should be remove and new div should be visible at exist div place in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose btn1 and btn2, on clicking btn1, the first div will show and on clicking btn2 second should be visible at first div place.

That means the first div should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

No need for JS.

You can use a technique called `anchor` + `:target`. You use an anchor to call a specific element by its ID. Then you use CSS to hide the lements with `display: none;`. to show them on an anchor click you use `element:target { display: block; }`

```css
#div-1,
#div-2 {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}

#div-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#div-2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div-1:target,
#div-2:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#div-1"> Show Div 1 </a>
<br>
<a href="#div-2"> Show Div 2 </a>
<div id="div-1"> Div 1 </div>
<div id="div-2"> Div 2 </div>
```

If you want to use JS, then you need to use fucntions and use: `document.querySelector("#id").style.display: "block/none";`

```js
let one = document.querySelector("#div-1"),
    two = document.querySelector("#div-2");

function showDivOne() {
  one.style.display = "block";
  two.style.display = "none";
}

function showDivTwo() {
  one.style.display = "none";
  two.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#div-1,
#div-2 {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}

#div-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#div-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showDivOne()"> Show Div 1 </button>
<br>
<button onclick="showDivTwo()"> Show Div 2 </button>
<div id="div-1"> Div 1 </div>
<div id="div-2"> Div 2 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple alternative realization on JQuery:

```js
const divOne = $("#div-1");
const divTwo = $("#div-2");

function btnClick(div) {

  if (div === "div1") {
    divOne.show();
    divTwo.hide();
  } else if (div === "div2") {
    divOne.hide();
    divTwo.show();
  } else {
    divOne.hide();
    divTwo.hide();
  }
}
```

```css
#div-1,
#div-2 {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}

#div-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#div-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button onclick="btnClick('div1')"> Show Div 1 </button>
  <button onclick="btnClick('div2')"> Show Div 2 </button>
  <button onclick="btnClick()"> Hide both </button>
</div>
<div id="div-1"> Div 1 </div>
<div id="div-2"> Div 2 </div>
```

Comment: btw @tacoshy tnx for your "anchor + :target" answer, is awesome, upvoted!

Comment: as a little advice to imrpove your jQuery script: Dont nest so much `if/else` statements. They can slow down as they requrie much more of the computing power. In your case you should use `switch statements`: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-switch-statement/

Comment: got it! I'll improve my skills!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what if there is needs to perform with hundreds of divs. Please help me with this. in javascript. Thankyou

Comment: @SatishKumarMaurya Could you please provide more details about how  exactly you will generate "hundreds of divs", some html code or so, toI can be more exactly in my answer too

Comment: I want to use html, CSS and js